# Incomplete filtering in dplyr....why?

Tags: r, dplyr

Below I have included a subset of my data and some `dplyr` code. The `AA` `filter` statement works as expected. However, the `BB` `filter` statement fails to remove all groups specified in `Filter.taxa`. Any ideas why this is occurring and potential fixes? I have already ensured that spelling and spacing are consistent throughout my data set.

The desired results for `BB` is provided.

I know that I can code individual `filter` statements in `BB` for each group in `Filter.taxa`, but this is cumbersome. I will be filtering different groups from numerous data sets and would like to specify the groups to be filter in a single line of code.

Thanks in advance.

```
DATE    SAMPLE  TAXA    GENUS   1
6/30/2013   Aqu-Pool-1  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Pool-2  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Pool-3  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Pool-4  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Riff-1  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Riff-2  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Riff-3  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Riff-4  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Wood-1  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Wood-2  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Wood-3  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
6/30/2013   Aqu-Wood-4  51  Rhyacophila_nocoh   5
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-1  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-2  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-3  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-4  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-1  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-2  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-3  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-4  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-1  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-2  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-3  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-4  43  Arctopsyche_3   10
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-1  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-2  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-3  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-4  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-1  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-2  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-3  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-4  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-1  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-2  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-3  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-4  164 Polycentropodidae   1000

Filter.taxa = c("Rhyacophila_nocoh", "Arctopsyche_3")
AA = filter(GENUS %in% Filter.taxa)
BB = filter(GENUS != Filter.taxa)
```

Desired result for `BB`:

```
DATE    SAMPLE  TAXA    GENUS   1
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-1  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-2  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-3  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Pool-4  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-1  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-2  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-3  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Riff-4  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-1  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-2  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-3  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
11/6/2013   Aqu-Wood-4  164 Polycentropodidae   1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%in%` for multiple elements and then negate (`!`). The `!=` can be used for single element just like `==`

```
 filter(df, !GENUS %in% Filter.taxa)
```